# Tinymce paste with min font 14pt

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor

How can i set to paste texts, from word for example, with minnimum font size of 14pt?
Heres my current code

```
tinymce.init({
      selector: '#campaign-description',
      menubar:false,
      height: 500,
      paste_as_text: true,
      fontsize_formats: '14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt',
      plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor save',
        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
      ],
      toolbar: 'undo redo | fontselect | fontsizeselect | sizeselect | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media | responsivefilemanager | code',
      content_css: [
        '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css'
      ],
      file_picker_types: 'image',
        file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
            if(type=='image') $('#file_name').click(); $('#field_name').val(field_name);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `paste` plugin will bring in the styles provided by Word.  There is no logic in the plugin to modify the style calculations.

For any tags that don't have inline styles you can just use `content_css` to set defaults.  If you want paragraphs to be 14pt just make a CSS rule that renders them that way.

If there are inline styles on the content you could use a paste_postprocess filter and calculate these changes yourself after the Paste plugin is done and before the code is inserted into the editor:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_postprocess